project-8-token-lottery: Error InvalidSecpSignature when run anchor test
I am very grateful for your knowledge to be shared. Through the knowledge you share I learn many new and very interesting things.
while practicing project-8-token-lottery. I get an error when running Anchor test. It is the error: "Program log: AnchorError occurred. Error Code: InvalidSecpSignature. Error Number: 6016. Error Message: InvalidSecpSignature". I have tried many ways but have not fixed it. Please give me advice. Thank you so much!

my code in Anchor test
it("Is committing and revealing a winner",async()=>{

const queue = new anchor.web3.PublicKey("FfD96yeXs4cxZshoPPSKhSPgVQxLAJUT3gefgh84m1Di"); //devnet
const queueAccount = new sb.Queue(switchboardProgram, queue);
const rngKp = anchor.web3.Keypair.generate();


try {
  await queueAccount.loadData(); 
} catch (err) {
  console.log("Queue account not found");
  process.exit(1);
}
const [randomness, ix] = await sb.Randomness.create(switchboardProgram, rngKp, queue);
console.log("Created randomness account..");
console.log("Randomness account", randomness.pubkey.toBase58());
console.log("rkp account", rngKp.publicKey.toBase58());

const createRandomnessTx = await sb.asV0Tx({
  connection:provider. connection,
  ixs: [ix],
  payer: wallet.publicKey,
  signers: [wallet.payer,rngKp],
  computeUnitPrice: 75_000,
  computeUnitLimitMultiple: 1.3,
});
const blockhashContext = await provider.connection.getLatestBlockhashAndContext();

const createRandomnessSignature = await provider.connection.sendTransaction(createRandomnessTx);
await provider.connection.confirmTransaction({ //sign the transaction
  signature: createRandomnessSignature,
  blockhash: blockhashContext.value.blockhash,
  lastValidBlockHeight: blockhashContext.value.lastValidBlockHeight
});
console.log(
  "Transaction Signature for randomness account creation: ",
  createRandomnessSignature
);

const sbCommitIx = await randomness.commitIx(queue); 

 // commint a winer on chain.
  const commitIx = await program.methods.commitAWinner()
  .accounts(
    {
      randomnessAccountData: randomness.pubkey
    }
  )
  .instruction();
  const commitTx = await sb.asV0Tx({
    connection: switchboardProgram.provider.connection,
    ixs: [sbCommitIx, commitIx],
    payer: wallet.publicKey,
    signers: [wallet.payer],
    computeUnitPrice: 75_000,
    computeUnitLimitMultiple: 1.3,
  });

  const commitSignature = await provider.connection.sendTransaction(commitTx);
  await provider.connection.confirmTransaction({
    signature: commitSignature,
    blockhash: blockhashContext.value.blockhash,
    lastValidBlockHeight: blockhashContext.value.lastValidBlockHeight
  });
  console.log(
    "Transaction Signature for commit: ",
    commitSignature
  );

// choose a winer
const sbRevealIx = await randomness.revealIx();
const revealIx = await program.methods.choseWiner()
  .accounts({
    randomnessAccountData: randomness.pubkey
  })
  .instruction();


const revealTx = await sb.asV0Tx({
  connection: switchboardProgram.provider.connection,
  ixs: [sbRevealIx,revealIx],
  payer: wallet.publicKey,
  signers: [wallet.payer],
  computeUnitPrice: 75_000,
  computeUnitLimitMultiple: 1.3,
});

const revealSignature = await provider.connection.sendTransaction(revealTx);
await provider.connection.confirmTransaction({
  signature: revealSignature,
  blockhash: blockhashContext.value.blockhash,
  lastValidBlockHeight: blockhashContext.value.lastValidBlockHeight
});
// await provider.connection.confirmTransaction(revealSignature,"confirmed");
console.log("Transaction Signature revealTx: ", revealSignature);

});

You might need to look through the Switchboard documentation or find a direct channel to contact them -- I don't know if they check the Stack Exchange unfortunately

Apparently the signature is wrong.
You can checkout how to make a lottery program here: https://medium.com/@edinaldo-jr/beyond-simple-tutorials-building-a-lottery-game-on-solana-blockchain-with-anchor-and-rust-7c3d5fe3963a
